# Elastica search add a second filter

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm starting using Elastica with my Symfony app but I'm stuck to add a filter.
The following code works well, it search by name, slug, agglomeration and then add a geoloc filter. I want to add a "specialty" filter to remove all results which do not correspond to that filter/ have that specialty but I've no idea how to do that.

```
        $nameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
        $nameQuery->setFieldQuery('name', $name);

        $slugQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
        $slugQuery->setFieldQuery('slug', $name);

        $agglomerationQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
        $agglomerationQuery->setFieldQuery('agglomeration', $agglomeration);

        $boolQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();
        $boolQuery->addShould($nameQuery);
        $boolQuery->addShould($slugQuery);
        $boolQuery->addShould($agglomerationQuery);

        //todo add filter by speciality

        if($latitude != null) {                
            $geoFilter = new \Elastica_Filter_GeoDistance('location', $latitude, $longitude, '3km');
            $boolQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Filtered($boolQuery, $geoFilter);
        }
        return $this->find($boolQuery);
```